# What directory to use in Linux to install python scripts

Tags: linux, debian, python, debian-installer, debian-policy

I have a workflow automation system that uses python scripts to run a workflow defined in them. I'm buiding a `deb` package and in doubt where to install those scripts.

**I currently in doubt if I should put them in `/usr/lib/workflow_automate` or `/usr/share/workflow_automate`.**

So it would look something like this:

```
/usr/share/workflow_automate/wf_script1.py
/usr/share/workflow_automate/wf_script2.py
```

**UPD:**

The system expects to configure an environment variable containing a path to a configuration file. The configuration file is expected to contain a path to a directory the scripts are contained in.

There is a daemon process of the workflow system which monitors the configured directories for changes.

Comment: Are these scripts that a user is expected to run on the command line? If so, consider installing them in a `bin` directory (e.g. `/usr/bin`) and without a `.py` filename suffix.

Comment: @Kusalananda No, not directly run. But the system expects to configure environment variable containg a path to a configuration file. The configuration file is expected to contain a path to a directory the scripts are contained in.

Comment: @Kusalananda Updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As this package won't be from an official repository, I'd suggest using `/usr/local`. There you have a similar structure as under `/`. This way you can easily manage local-admin installed things and not introduce conflicts with any potential official distribution software.

Comment: Would `/usr/local/lib/my-wf-scripts` be a reasonable choice? I think it is more suitable for `lib` than `share`, but I have some doubts...

Comment: @SomeName I guess both are ok. I don't think it's very important. Personally, I'd rather put them in `share` as long they're not a module (which they may be?). You can consult this also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard